# Sinon spy return "undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I'm on node.js using Mongoose model and testing with Mocha with Sinon.

The function I'm testing:

```
exports.findAllUsers = (req, res) => {
UserCollection.find()
    .then(users => {
        res.status(500)
           .send(users)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500)
            .send({message: err.message || "error occurred retriving users informations"})
    })
```

Here my test code:

```
describe("findAllUsers", () => {
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
afterEach(function () {
  sinon.restore();
  sandbox.restore();
});

const req = {
  params: {
    id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  },
};
const statusJsonSpy = sinon.spy();
const res = {
  send: sinon.spy(),
  status: sinon.stub().returns({ json: statusJsonSpy }),
};

it("should return all users data if found", async () => {
  mongoose.Model.find = sandbox
    .stub()
    .returns(Promise.resolve("users data"));
    await findAllUsers(req, res);

    console.log(res.send.callCount);
    expect(res.send).to.have.been.calledWith("users data");
});
```

res.send.callCount return 0, res.send is never been called thus the test fail!

Answer (score 0):

If I edit my function as in the following, the test work:

```
exports.findAllUsers = (req, res) => {
UserCollection.find()
    .then(users => {
        res.status(500)
        res.send(users) // added res, not using concatenation
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500)
            .send({message: err.message || "error occurred retriving users informations"})
    })
```

}